# iOS: Issue Saving Photo

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, save

I'm very new to Objective-C, and am having some beginner issues. I have an application that has an area that is supposed to behave somewhat like a photo gallery. The user chooses a picture from their camera roll, and the photos get displayed in UIImageViews. I'm trying to save the image that they select. I have 9 UIImageView's, and the issue is that when I select a different photo for each UIImageView, close and relaunch the app, the other 8 UIImageViews display the photo that is stored in the first image view. Here is the code that I'm working with:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                         NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename9];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    NSLog(@"Image on didenterbackground: %@", imageView);
    self.imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)];
    self.imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView2.image)];
    self.imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView3.image)];
    self.imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView4.image)];
    self.imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView5.image)];
    self.imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView6.image)];
    self.imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView7.image)];
    self.imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView8.image)];
    self.imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView9.image)];

    [self.imageData writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"The image is: %@", [[imageView image] description]);
    NSLog(@"dataFilePath is: %@", [self dataFilePath]);

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    NSLog(@"FilePath: %@", filePath);
    NSLog(@"Image: %@", imageView);
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSData *vdlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:vdlData];
        imageView2.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:vdlData];
        imageView3.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:vdlData];
        imageView4.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:vdlData];
        imageView5.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:vdlData];
        imageView6.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:vdlData];
        imageView7.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:vdlData];
        imageView8.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:vdlData];
        imageView9.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:vdlData];
    }


    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:app];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

I'm trying to figure out what I need to change to get the UIImageViews to display the correct pictures, rather than them all displaying the same picture. This is probably a simple fix, but any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you notice that you are allocating each imageView with the same image stored at vdlData...and you are storing each image to the same variable (overwriting each other) before you save it to one path (dataFilePath)?

Comment: Oh wow, how did I miss that. Thank you. Would it be fine to save all the variables to one path or should I have a different path for each variable?

Comment: Here I'll make it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's how I would do it:

Use NSUserDefaults to save your images as a mutable array:

**ViewController.h**

```
@property(retain) NSUserDefaults *user;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@synthesize user;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    self.user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

**Edit**

```
    NSMutableArray* array = [[self.user objectForKey:@"images"]mutableCopy];
    while(array == nil)
    {
       [self.user setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@""] forKey:@"images"]
       array = [[self.user objectForKey:@"images"]mutableCopy];
       NSLog(@"%@",@"attempting to create an array to store the images in");
    }
```

**End Edit**
    }

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    NSLog(@"Image on didenterbackground: %@", imageView);
    NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)]];

    [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView2.image)];
    [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView3.image)];
    [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView4.image)];
    [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView5.image)];
    [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView6.image)];
    [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView7.image)];
    [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView8.image)];
    [array addObject:[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView9.image)];

    [self.user setObject:array forKey:@"images"];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray* array = [[self.user objectForKey:@"images"]mutableCopy];
```

**EDIT**

```
    if(array.count == 9)
    {
    imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
    imageView2.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:1]];
    imageView3.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:2]];
    imageView4.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:3]];
    imageView5.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:4]];
    imageView6.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:5]];
    imageView7.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:6]];
    imageView8.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:7]];
    imageView9.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[array objectAtIndex:8]];
    }
```

**END EDIT**

```
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:app];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.user = nil;
}
```

This way, you will not lose the images or data, they will be stored and easily accessed, and they will not disappear even if you update your app.

Cheers!

Comment: No problem. I realized that I helped you the other day with another of your questions. Ha ha, small site, even though it's not.

Comment: Lol yeah you did man, you've been a lifesaver. I do have one more question, I implement your code but for some reason its not saving any of the images, should I add in a return anywhere? Thaks again man!

Comment: If you don't need to have the png representation, you could just save them as an array of UIImages...also, add what I added in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Before I start with the solution, I have to warn you that the way you're doing this isn't the right one. I suggest that you start learning iOS development from the ground up. Apple's own documentation is a pretty good start. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Now, back to your question. What you do here is save only one image, not all 9 of them. You set `self.imageData` always with each image you process and you overwrite its previous value, making only the last image to be saved to file.

So, in order to make your code working, you would have to use an `imageData` object for each image view, then write that data object to file.

In your case, it's probably best to optimize the code by using loops, instead using multiple objects (like `imageView`, `imageView2`, ...).

Also, make sure that you take care of your memory. e.g. `imageView.image` is allocated but not released.

Comment: -1 please turn the first paragraph into specific advice or just delete it. Also feel free to use backticks to mark miniature code blocks for readability. I can reverse the minus-1 when you fix the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see two issues. First and foremost, in `viewDidLoad`, all your images are getting initWithData:vdlData... so they're all getting the same data. That's why they're all the same.

Also, when you're trying to save them, in `...didEnterBackground`, you are overwriting the value of `imageData` over and over again... when you save it, it's just the last one you've assigned to `imageData`. You probably want to create an `NSArray`, and store them in there, pulling them out of the array in `viewDidLoad`.